# unable to read the attribute value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this method on rowmouseevent

`$get(eventArgs.get_id())` gives the ouput as

```
<tr class="normal" data-value="normal" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UserGrid_grdusergrid_ctl00__0" style="height:30px;" /tr>
```

How can I get the "class" attribute value of that

I am trying like

```
$get(eventArgs.get_id()).attr("class")
```

which is throws error as below
"Object # has no method 'attr'"

Thanks

Comment: what this $get(eventArgs.get_id()) is returning

Comment: Your html output is also malformed, or is that just a copy & paste fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$($get(eventArgs.get_id())).attr("class")
```

Comment: Thanks Justus,rajesh,hicurin,Royi Namir,Shaik Rilwan and Marshall Farrier this worked

Answer (score 2):

$get is a function from the (now depreciated) ms ajax core JavaScript library and attr is jquery function. So you have to wrap your $get element with $(Jquery) to use attr like:

```
$($get(eventArgs.get_id())).attr("class")
```

or If you know the element id then you can directly use

```
$('#Id).attr("class")
```

Comment: Thanks rajesh $($get(eventArgs.get_id())).attr("class") worked

Answer (score 1):

If `$get` (don't know what that is) really returns that HTML node, you still have to wrap it with jQuery to enhance it with all the features, like `attr`:

```
$get(eventArgs.get_id()) // return <tr class="normal" ... etc ...
$($get(eventArgs.get_id())) // returns jquery object, with <tr class="normal ...
$($get(eventArgs.get_id())).attr("class") // now you can do this
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#'+$get(eventArgs.get_id())).attr("class");
```

Comment: why `.` and not `#` ?  `get_id` returns obviously an `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

`$('#'+$get(eventArgs.get_id())).prop("class");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var className = $('<tr class="normal" data-value="normal" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UserGrid_grdusergrid_ctl00__0" style="height:30px;" ></tr>').attr('class');
```

or

```
 var obj = $("'" + $get(eventArgs.get_id() + "'").attr('class');
```